# Changing HTML content on menu item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the content of the yellow area when the user clicks on 'Dashboard', 'customers' etc: [Here is the template I used](http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/pvqvxO)

First I tried to change `index.js` I gave an id to div area:

```
$('.icon-dashboard').on('click', function() {
    $("#area").load("secondpage.html #area > *");
});
```

This didn't work for me. Any suggestions to change the content between main tags?

Comment: Create a fiddle or codepen so we can see what is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for the load command is wrong.  Your HTML shows a `<main>` tag with `<div class="helper">` so you would want to use `$("main .helper").load(...)` to load content into "helper".  Or, if you want to replace the "helper" div with whatever comes back from .load, just do `$("main").load(...)`.

Also, passing "secondpage.html" to .load() is only going to work in the local browser.  I'm assuming you're only doing that because you're testing?  Ultimately, you'll need some backend script at an URL to return your content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want it to work only on localhost. Just trying to learn how it functions. I tried what you said but it didn't work for me or I could not implement it correctly?

Comment: Chances are, your selector after "secondpage.html" is wrong.  Look at that file and see if there's anything with ``id="area"``.  If not, you'll have to figure out what element you want to get the content from, and build a selector that matches that element.  Add `` > *`` if you want only the contents, and not the element itself.